# importing with ctrl+space inserts unwanted text

Tags: visual-studio-code

I press ctrl+space and select import but then the name of the variable changes and vs code adds text into it.

For example:

```
import { Hello} from "./entities/Post"

const main = async () => {
    const orm = await MikroORM.init({
        entities: [Hello],
    })
}

main()
```

After selecting the Hello and ctrl+space to import, the Hello will change to Hellollo, or something like that